# VSTS-GITHUB Workflow

Tags: github, azure-devops

Please elaborate the steps to create a workflow of Visual
    Studio Team Services and Github.
    Integration of Github with VSTS and creating a workflow.
    Once we create user stories in vsts, is there any way to create a 
    transition from one state to another(New->Active->resolved),
    based on repository update(github).

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to transition from on state to another when github repo is update:

1. Create a CI build definition for the github repo.
2. Add a power shell task to change the stories state.

But usually user stories are linked with repo on VSTS not github, that’s more useful and meaningful.

Comment: Thanks Marina.
Is this the same for GITLAB?

Comment: Yes, almost.The different is choose get source from **Remote repo** in a build definition **Get Sources**, other steps are same.

Answer (score 0):

Automatically is only using VSTS git repo.
If you like update this, you need to create a manual integration, possible using the VSTS Rest Api.